# Rotations in 3D Figure

Tags: geometry

I am trying to obtain all the rotational axes present in the 3d figure where all six faces are equal rhombus (I tried attaching a photo of the figure I found online but I can't post it). Can someone help me understand on how to start it and visualize it? Maybe locate the axes of those of order 2 and order 3 rotation first and after getting a better understanding I will try to get by myself those of higher orders.

Comment: Why, there are many ways. Make yourself a model out of clay, or bubble-gum, or other pliable material. Or create one in a 3D editor of your choosing. Or just imagine it really well in your head. We don't know what will work for you.

Comment: I think that's where my problem lies, I have a hard time imagining and understanding where the points will go under the rotation and also locating the rotational axes. I get the order 2 and order 4 rotations in cubes but not order 3. And it has now become even harder since the faces are now rhombi. So I was hoping someone could sketch out even just some of the order 2 and order 3 rotation axes to help me start visualizing what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Then I guess we aren't getting anywhere without a real-world 3D model which you'd be able to actually rotate in your fingers. Find them 3-order axes in a cube. Do you know where they are?